# removing leading and trailing backlash in key value in JSON documents

Tags: python, regex, json

I have the following JSON structure.

```
"bent": "{
       \"ActiveT\": 6,
        \"ErrorM\": \"None\",
        \"Except\": \"None\",
        \"HadErr\": \"false\",
        \"HM\": 62,
        \"NHM\": 57,
        \"Parameter\": \"14331232706\",
        \"ReturnCode\": \"3050\",
        \"Severity\": \"info\",
        \"Timestamp\": \"Tue July0209: 58: 16NZST2015\",
        \"TId\": \"9891319709\",
        \"UserInfo\": \"Unknown\",
    }"
```

I want to remove the `\` at the beginning and the end of each of the `key` and `value` in the JSON structure.I want to do this using python regular expressions.

Comment: Whys specifically regex? you can do that using normal string replace

Comment: @nu11p01n73R - That could work as well.How to check the position of `\` without using any anchors.

Comment: @nhahtdh - strange question? what makes you think they aren't there?

Comment: @liv2hak: If this is a string containing JSON, if you parse the parent JSON with a JSON parser, the resulting string shouldn't contain any escape sequence for the `"`.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
>>> print re.sub(r'\\(?=")', '', string)
"bent": "{
       "ActiveT": 6,
        "ErrorM": "None",
        "Except": "None",
        "HadErr": "false",
        "HM": 62,
        "NHM": 57,
        "Parameter": "14331232706",
        "ReturnCode": "3050",
        "Severity": "info",
        "Timestamp": "Tue July0209: 58: 16NZST2015",
        "TId": "9891319709",
        "UserInfo": "Unknown",
    }
```

**Regex  explanation**

- `\\` Matches the `\`
- `(?=")` Positive look ahead. Checks if the `\` is followed by `"`
- Replace it with empty string.

---

**OR**

Using [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

```
>>> print string.replace('\\"', '"')
"bent": "{
       "ActiveT": 6,
        "ErrorM": "None",
        "Except": "None",
        "HadErr": "false",
        "HM": 62,
        "NHM": 57,
        "Parameter": "14331232706",
        "ReturnCode": "3050",
        "Severity": "info",
        "Timestamp": "Tue July0209: 58: 16NZST2015",
        "TId": "9891319709",
        "UserInfo": "Unknown",
    }
```

Comment: Note that there is more than just the `"` which can be escaped. There can also be Unicode escape sequences.

Comment: @nhahtdh Sorry I didn't get you. But the `\\"` will find all escaped `"` only and not any other escape sequance

Comment: My point is - you only solve whatever problem as seen from the OP's perspective without considering the bigger picture. When there are JSON parsing facilities, I don't think we should process JSON like this at all, and doing it like this is very error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions here sounds like the wrong approach. If this was actual JSON data (I assume the `{` and `}` are missing from your example) the right answer is to parse it properly:

```
d1 = json.loads(data)
d2 = json.loads(d1['bent'])
```

Comment: I can't find json.parse() in python

Comment: Did you mean json.loads() ?